# XOR two blocks in python

Tags: python, sage

i am new to programming in python...i want to make XOR between 2 blocks here is my code

```
def XorBlock(block1, block2):
    l = len(block1);
    if (l != len(block2)):
        raise ValueError, "XorBlock arguments must be same length"
    return [(block1[j]+block2[j]) % 2 for j in xrange(l)];
```

but when i call it gives me

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

so please anyone help me where is the bug in this code..thanks in advance

Comment: make sure both lists' elements are numbers, not strings.

Comment: when i make it integer it gives me this TypeError: object of type 'sage.rings.integer.Integer' has no len()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
def XorBlock(block1, block2):
    l = len(block1)
    if l != len(block2):
        raise ValueError
    #         |-> Converting into int
    return [(int(block1[j])+int(block2[j])) % 2 for j in xrange(l)]
    #                        |-> Converting into int


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print XorBlock("12345", "23456")
```

---

```
>>> XorBlock("010101", "108734")
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

I decided that keeping both arguments as strings would be best, as in binary, you may have to have some `0`s before any digits of value.

Comment: could you please tell me what if __name__ == '__main__': means ??

Comment: @ranatamer Well, its like a `main` function in C++. Basically, if python is running the current file, then the `__name__` of the file becomes `__main__`. In this example, you really don't need to use it, you can just type in `XorBlock("12345", "23456")`, and it will work just fine.

Comment: @ranatamer Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do). It explains it better than I did.

Answer (score 0):

This part is wrong, take a look:

```
(block1[j]+block2[j]) % 2
```

both items are string, therefore, the result is a string. In short, python treats your `%2` as  a string formatting command.

```
"string"%something
```

will expect the string to specify where it should format `something`. If it doesn't specify anything, the current `TypeError` will be raised. What you probably need is something like this:

```
return[(int(block1[j])+int(block2[j])) % 2 for j in xrange(l)]
#This converts it to integers, then xor it.
```

Hope this helps!